# Skobbler POI grouping priority

Tags: ios, dictionary, skmaps

I am using Skobbler map for iOS application.
Is it possible to set priority for POI category so when multiple POIs group, icon of that category be on top?

So if info icon has higher priority it should be shown in group icon instead of restaurant.

[image]

I tried to set priority tag of category in json style file but it didn't work.

Comment: We are looking into it to see what is possible (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you desire the Information POI to be made visible at a lower zoom level instead of the current Restaurant POI.
 If this is the case, you can achieve this by changing which POI should remain at the lower zoom level, so when you zoom out only that specific POI will be visible. 
  This can be done by editing in the .json file the "zoom" which is found at the bottom of the document .
  From there, you find the code snippet for your desired zoom level -for example at lvl 17, it should contain the next line "level" : 17, then you should change in the "poi":[........] array the ID of Restaurant which is 179 with the ID for Informations which is 128 and there you go, now when zooming from lvl 18 to lvl 17 from those 3 POIs only Information will be visible. 
Here I will add a snippet for zoom lvl 7 (because it has less POIs,shapes,roads) to aid you when searching for the zoom level declaration in the .json file:

```
{
"3dzoomfactor" : 1.0,
"attribute" : [ 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44 ],
"level" : 7,
"maxFC" : [ 3, 2, 2, 2 ],
"poi" : [ 69, 211, 193, 418, 382, 383, 82, 416 ],
"road" : [ 9, 24, 13 ],
"shape" : [ 1016, 1015, 1031 ],
"worldtexture" : [ true, true, true, true ]
}
```

Comment: No. I want to all POIs be visible no matter of zoom level. But when POIs are grouped into one, information icon is show (on icon with number 2, on image) instead of restaurant icon.